# Symfony forms : Collect array of data

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I need to collect array of data via input fields. For example:

```
<input name="customer_name" type="text">
<input name="customer_emails[]" type="text">
<input name="customer_emails[]" type="text">
<input name="customer_emails[]" type="text">
```

How to render this type of form in Symfony2 form builder?

Documentation says:

```
$builder->add('emails', 'collection', array(
    // each item in the array will be an "email" field
    'type'   => 'email',
    // these options are passed to each "email" type
    'options'  => array(
        'required'  => false,
        'attr'      => array('class' => 'email-box')
    ),
));
```

It is not clear to me where I should provide the number of email fields I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What @kix said was absolutely correct.

However, if you want to offer initial number of fields you could:

```
$object = ... # Some object... 
$object->setEmail(array("", "", "")); # for example, 3 addresses
$form = $this->createForm(new SomeFormType(), $object);

####
# REST OF YOUR LOGIC
####

$view = $form->createView();
```

Answer (score 3):

The exact number of collection fields is determined by the model that's bound to the form. Take a closer look at the last paragraph in Symfony's [`collection` field type documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#basic-usage):

> In both cases, no input fields would render unless your emails data
>   array already contained some emails.
>
> In this simple example, it's still impossible to add new addresses or
>   remove existing addresses. Adding new addresses is possible by using
>   the allow_add option (and optionally the prototype option) (see
>   example below). Removing emails from the emails array is possible with
>   the allow_delete option.

Thus, if you need to accept three email addresses, make sure that the data that's bound to the form has the according values set up, or consider `'allow_add'` option of the `collection` type.